# combobox.ui Jquery start autocomplete on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i'm working on combox.ui which was earlier changed by one of my senior. He changed js file according to our project's needs.But my need is now whenever someone focus on dropdown       --Select -- should be removed from list and autocomplete search should start and whenever focus is out of dropdown or input --Select-- should be added at its place. Please tell me where i'm doing wrong and where this function should be written. I've no idea where to write this function in this plugin code..

```
(function ($) {
$.widget("ui.combobox", {
    options: {
        maxOptionSize: 20,
        maxOptionText: "... type to filter"
    },
    _create: function () {
        var self = this,
            select = this.element.hide(),
            selected = select.children(":selected"),
            maxOptionValue = select.children().eq(0).val(),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        select.wrap("<div style='float:left;'></div>");

        var width = $(select).width();
        if (width == 0)
            width = 100;

        if (this.element.attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {/*To handle disabled case */
            input = this.input = $("<input type='textbox'>").addClass("textbox").attr("disabled", "disabled").insertAfter(select).val(value).attr("title", value);
            return; /*Do not render autocomplete*/
        }
        var input = this.input = $("<input>").insertAfter(select).val(value).attr("title", value).autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: function (request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                var select_el = select.get(0); // get dom element
                var rep = new Array(); // response array
                input.data("autocomplete").showMaxOption = false;
                // simple loop for the options
                for (var i = 0; i < select_el.length; i++) {
                    var text = select_el.options[i].text;
                    // add element to result array
                    if (select_el.options[i].value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) {
                        rep.push({
                            label: text, //.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                            value: text,
                            option: select_el.options[i],
                            number: i + 1
                        });
                    }
                    if (rep.length == self.options.maxOptionSize) {
                        input.data("autocomplete").showMaxOption = true;
                        input.data("autocomplete").maxOptionText = self.options.maxOptionText;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // send response
                response(rep);
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {

                if (ui.item.value == maxOptionValue) {
                    input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                    var selValue = select.find("option:selected").text();
                    $(this).val(selValue).attr("title", selValue);

                    return false;
                } else {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    self._trigger("selected", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                }
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {

                if (ui.item.value == maxOptionValue) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {

                if (!ui.item) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                        valid = false;
                    select.children("option").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            select.change();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!valid) {
                        input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                        var selValue = select.find("option:selected").text();
                        $(this).val(selValue).attr("title", selValue);
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    var selValue = select.find("option:selected").text();
                    $(this).attr("title", selValue);
                }
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                if (event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.type === "menuselected") {
                    $(select).change();
                }
            }
        }).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left").width(width);

        input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
        };

        this.button = $("<button type='button'>&nbsp;</button>").attr("tabIndex", -1).attr("title", "Show Items").insertAfter(input).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
        }).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon").click(function () {
            // close if already visible                
            if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                input.autocomplete("close");
                return;
            }

            // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
            $(this).blur();

            // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete("search", "");
            input.focus();
        });

        var iw = input.outerWidth(true);
        var bw = this.button.outerWidth(true);
        select.parent().width(iw + bw + 1);
    },
    destroy: function () {
        this.input.remove();
        this.button.remove();
        this.element.show();
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
    }
});
})(jQuery);
(function ($) {
$.extend($.ui.autocomplete.prototype, {
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var self = this;
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if (index < items.length)
                self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
        if (self.element.data("autocomplete").showMaxOption) {
            ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-max-option'>" +       self.element.data("autocomplete").maxOptionText + "</li>");
        }
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: its being implement on all the Dropdown on page...whether its using `<input type='select' />` or `<asp:Dropdownlist />`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you were asking for, --SELECT-- is removed on focus, and added back on blur.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/fsRn4/

**UPDATE:**

Show search on focus, and adds --SELECT-- only if another option is not selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/fsRn4/4/

**Resources:**

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11859219/922168

Comment: yes i want it to do like as you did...but intellisense/opetions should also shown after removal of select text...without clicking on dropdown button...that was my main problem..

Answer (score 2):

Just add `$(input).autocomplete('search','');` within input's onfocus() event, This will open up the combobox whenever the input is on focus. So based on Nick's fiddle, it will be like `input.focus(function(event) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(input).autocomplete('search','');
        });`

Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fsRn4/3/

Comment: Xnake, cool but still not perfect...check your Fiddle it doesn't works as it should be exactly... whenever you select an item from dropdown that's oaky...but if you click outside of dropdownn text is again changed to select...which should not happen...otherwise you almost made it and out of my tries i was at the same position ...however +1 for your effort... :)

Comment: makes sense, but wasn't well explained in the original specs, updated my answer to comply. Thanks for the help Xnake, +1. http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/fsRn4/4/